# Time Series Analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am focusing on implement an automated solution that will take as input many time series data (one at a time).

After padding any missing values in order to have a time series without gaps, I am trying to check whether each one is stationary or not and then proceed into using either hybridModel() or auto.arima() in order to get a proper forecasting.

One of the questions that have arisen is that I haven't found a complete solution/algorithm describing the steps one has to take to do so.

Specifically it is not clear to me what to do if p-value is not < 0.05 and is for instance between 95% and 90% , i.e. `0.05 < p-value < 0.1`. Is it stationary or not?
For instance after decomposing I get the screenshot below:

[image]

- I wonder whether I have to remove the trend in the series, and if that is the case how I could do so. It is not clear to me after the decomposition whether I have to get for instance the log() of my time series or find a way to remove the trend. Can this task be automated or it needs to be "supervised" in terms of having to beforehand examine the series decomposition etc?
- Why the seasonal seems so repeating even thought my time series shows one distinct spike during
- Finally, I found information about the procedure online but I haven't found a tutorial of explanatory step-by-step guide in order not to replicate existing solutions but to be able to produce tailored solutions as there are huge differences between the time series I examine.

Sorry for the long post, I tried to gather some time series questions in one place that I think will benefit others as well.

Comment: Try http://stats.stackexchange.com - this is a mostly statistical question and there are lots more statistics experts there.

Comment: You could install the `astsa` package and call `sarima(diff(log(myseries)), ... )` and then call it with the right parameters- e.g. `sarima(diff(log(AirPassengers)),0,0,1)`. Read the documentation at http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/tsaEZ.pdf and experiment.